# How do I handle mulitpart/form-data http request with python

Tags: python, http

I want to handle multipart/form-data with python.
The request will look like this.

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8000/uplaod.html
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------13077140074516507283069689500
Content-Length: 20970
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0

-----------------------------13077140074516507283069689500
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mylogo"; filename="logo.png"
Content-Type: image/png

image_byte_code

-----------------------------13077140074516507283069689500--
```

This will be received in bytes from client browser.
I need to decode it to string.
But when i decode it the image bytes get destroyed.
Which then when i save it it will not be an image.

I have so far been able to decode it and receive text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the email library that defaults with python can really help. you just split the header from the data then use this  https://julien.danjou.info/handling-multipart-form-data-python/.  Make sure you get the boundary data  from the headers.